# Node_Path NPM installing yeoman Atom

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

Trying to install Yeoman, I'm getting the error below, my Node Path is correctly set.

I searched the registry but don't know where npm is picking up the path ?
Running `Windows 7`

**error**

> Yeoman Doctor Running sanity checks on your system
>
> √ Global configuration file is valid √ Node.js version √ No .bowerrc
>   file in home directory √ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory √ npm
>   version x NODE_PATH matches the npm root npm global root value is not
>   in your NODE_PATH
>
> [Info]   **NODE_PATH =
>   C:\Users\Francois\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.0.7\resources\app.asar\
>   exports**   npm root  =
>   C:\Users\Francois\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
>
> [Fix] Append the npm root value to your NODE_PATH variable   If you're
>   using cmd.exe, run this command to fix the issue:
>       setx NODE_PATH "%NODE_PATH%;C:\Users\Francois\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul es"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok various issues, it seems that upgrading node might have something to do with it. What I ended up doing was to uninstall and delete all node and npm related files and environmental variables. Re-install and its working again, take a look at this post was similiar to my issues.
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8737